# Unable to Image Computer from Windows Deploy Service (Missing IP from DHCP?)

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, wds, imaging

so I'm trying to get a Windows Deploy Server up and running to deploy Windows 8.1 to a new HP computer (no OS previously installed), and I thought I had, but I keep getting an error every time I try to image a computer.

The Setup:

- I'm working with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

  I'm trying to deploy a copy of Windows 8.1 Enterprise to an HP EliteBook Folio 1040 G3 laptop.

  I added the Windows Deployment Service role through Server Manager, including successfully adding the Boot and Install Images.

  Also, our company's firewall acts as the DHCP server and is on the same subnet as both the deploy server, and the computer I'm trying to image.

  And I know the computer is being assigned an IP from the DHCP server, as when I log on to the firewall and check DHCP, I see the computer listed with both it's MAC and IP address.

The Fail:

- I'm able to PXE boot to the server.

  It connects and seems to get into Windows 8.1 install process, but after hanging on the Starting Setup window for a couple minutes, I then get the error

`WdsClient: An error occurred while obtaining an IP address from the DHCP server.`

Any and all ideas are welcome.

Comment: do you have the required drivers added to the boot image?

Answer (score 0):

Are DHCP and WDS installed on same computer? If answer is yes, then make sure ports 60 and 67 check marks in WDS properties.

If DHCP and WDS are installed SEparetely then would I recommend to watch this video.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kwoVwbkrads&itct=CBEQpDAiEwjW3pj3q4nRAhVNxpwKHYm3CywyC2M0LXZpZGVvcy11WhhVQzFMcnhhcDVPamJDVW9aTWw4Vk0wMFE%3D&client=mv-google&gl=IN&hl=en